# ERROR Maximum request length exceeded

Tags: asp.net, error-handling, exception, web-config, data-paging

- Grid View contains 15000 records and on first time time Page Load the GridView is binding perfectly.
- But on any other PostBack event causing the following error.

**Maximum request length exceeded.**

We have tried increasing the value of aspnet:MaxHttpCollectionKeys

```
<add key="aspnet:MaxHttpCollectionKeys" value="10000" />
```

And

httpRuntime Tag under system.web

```
<httpRuntime maxRequestLength="1048576" executionTimeout="3600" />
```

Thanks in advance...............